# Excel - How to split semi-colon separated values in multiple columns into rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, delimiter, excel-365

I have a table in Excel with following format

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | A;B;C;D | 1;2;3;4 | a;b;c;d |
| beta | E;F | 0;5 | x;y |

How do I split each corresponding values in columns to rows?

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | A | 1 | a |
| alpha | B | 2 | b |
| alpha | C | 3 | c |
| alpha | D | 4 | d |
| beta | E | 0 | x |
| beta | F | 5 | y |

I tried power query (from Table/Range) -> Split column by delimiter (Advanced -> into rows). But I quickly get a lot of duplicated values and removing duplicates can be challenging.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this without a macro?

**EDIT**: Added new column (Col1) to understand repetition of single values in a column is handled when splitting values in other columns into rows.

Comment: You can do text to columns first then paste with transpose?

Comment: I have >15 columns that have this type of values and doing them manually quickly becomes inefficient. Any other suggestions?

Comment: 'doing it manually quickly becomes inefficient' - that's generally the situation you'd need a macro for.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes understand and I have no problems with macros. Was wondering if this could be achieved with power query. Any suggestions?

Comment: A little bit based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73852522/9758194) answer you could try `=LET(X,BYCOL(A1:C2,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(";",,a))),Y,INDEX(X,1),Z,LEN(Y)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Y,";",""))+1,MAKEARRAY(Z,COLUMNS(A1:C1),LAMBDA(r,c,TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(";"& INDEX(X,1,c)&";",";",r+1),";",-1))))` and it should spill the entire matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes (Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
TableTransform = Table.Combine(List.Transform(List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(#"Changed Type"), (x) => List.Transform(Record.ToList(x), each Text.Split(_,";"))), each Table.FromColumns(_, Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"))))
in  TableTransform
```

[image]

**Update for changed requirements**:  right click and fill down a static column

[image]

Comment: In case it helps, here: [Split text to multiple rows - an alternative to TEXTSPLIT](https://superuser.com/questions/1726513/split-text-to-multiple-rows-an-alternative-to-textsplit) you can find the steps to follow with Power Query user interface for a similar problem.

Comment: @horseyride Thank you for the answer. Looking closely at my data, I updated the question with another column containing single values. How does your solution handle this case?

Comment: Did you try it?   If needed, right click the column and fill down

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data in the following range: `B1:D3` (including the header). You can achieve it for each column as follows in `F2`;

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,B2:B3),,";")
```

For the first column and then to extend the formula to the following columns.

A more concise way to achieve it for a large number of columns is to use the following formula (**Formula 1**):

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("", 
  BYCOL(B2:D3, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(";",,x))), 
  LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a="", b, a&","&b))),";",",",,,""))
```

[image: sample using reduce]

**Notes:**

1. Added more values to **Col1** and **Col2**, to validate it works when we have different number of rows in the table.
2. We use `pad_with` input argument from `TEXTSPLIT` to consider columns with different number of elements and to pad is as blank.
3. `REDUCE` is used to convert the entire input to a single string, adding a column delimiter (`,`). The result will be a string delimited rows with `;` and columns with `,`.
4. Finally `TEXTSPLIT` converts it back to an array format, we need to transpose the result because this function populates the information by row.

### Update for the new column added in the question

After the modification of the original question:

> EDIT: Added new column (Col1) to understand repetition of single
> values in a column is handled when splitting values in other columns
> into rows

Now we need to consider how to handle the first column. Let's say we have the new data set on the following range: `B13:D14`. This is just a modification of previous solution to consider the special case of the first column. Now we can replace the input range (`B2:D3`) in **(Formula 1)** with the following (**Formula 2**):

```
HSTACK(MAP(BYROW(MAP(A13:D14, LAMBDA(item,
 (LEN(item)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(item,";",""))))), 
 LAMBDA(xx, MAX(xx)+1)), A13:A14, LAMBDA(maxRows,value,
 LET(yy,REPT(value&";",maxRows), 
 LEFT(yy, LEN(yy)-1)))), B13:D14)
```

The above formula produces the following output:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha;alpha;alpha;alpha | A;B;C;D | 1;2;3;4 | a;b;c;d |
| beta;beta | E;F. | 0;5; | x;y |

The final formula in `F13` will be:

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("", BYCOL(HSTACK(MAP(BYROW(MAP(A13:D14, 
  LAMBDA(item,(LEN(item)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(item,";",""))))), 
  LAMBDA(xx, MAX(xx)+1)), A13:A14, 
  LAMBDA(maxRows,value, LET(yy,REPT(value&";",maxRows), 
  LEFT(yy, LEN(yy)-1)))), B13:D14), 
  LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(";",,x))), 
  LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a="", b, a&","&b))),";",",",,,""))
```

Here is the final result:
[image: version 2]

#### Explanation of Formula 2

`HSTACK` function is used to combine the following arrays: `[Col1*, B13:D14]` where `Col1*` represents the modified **Col1**, in a way we add the repetition of the first column based on the maximum number of rows we are going to generate per each row of the input dataset.

To calculate `Col1*` we need to determine the maximum number of rows and then repeat the original value as many time as rows we are going to generate.

*Let's start with the calculation of the maximum number of rows*: we do it by counting the number of `;` plus one. The idea for counting the number of occurrences of a specific character in a string was taken from here: [How to Count Characters in Excel](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/count/count-characters-in-excel), so in our case we use:

```
LEN(item)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(item,";",""))
```

The `MAP` function with two input arguments: `maxRows`,`value` in the `LAMBDA` function is used to build a new range, where the first argument represents an array with the maximum number of rows. It uses a inner `MAP` to do this calculation:

```
=BYROW(MAP(A13:D14, LAMBDA(item,
  (LEN(item)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(item,";",""))))), 
  LAMBDA(xx, MAX(xx)+1))
```

it returns:

```
| 4 |
| 2 |
```

The second argument (`value`) represents the cells from **Col1**: `A13:A14`.The outher `MAP` now repeats the **Col1** values based on the maximum number of rows (`maxRows`) calculated before and remove the `;` at the end.

```
=LET(yy,REPT(value&";",maxRows), 
 LEFT(yy, LEN(yy)-1))
```

you can test it separately with the following formula (hard coded the number of repetitions to `4` for testing purpose):

```
=BYROW(A13:A14, LAMBDA(value,
  LET(yy,REPT(value&";",4), LEFT(yy, LEN(yy)-1))))
```

it produce the following output:

```
|alpha;alpha;alpha;alpha |
|beta;beta;beta;beta     |
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I can't find "TEXTSPLIT" function in Excel. I am using Excel in Office 365. It looks like functions "TEXTSPLIT", "REDUCE", "BYCOL" are only available in Office Insider Beta channel of Excel 365

Comment: @Rock, all of them are available in Office 365, the only limitation is [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7#:~:text=Splits%20text%20strings%20by%20using,inverse%20of%20the%20TEXTJOIN%20function.) It indicates some specific availability. I am so confuse with so many similar version names. I think am using *Excel for Web*, that is free and comes with my Microsoft account. I prefer to use Google Spreadsheet, but I am forced to use Excel in my job. Some alternative without that function will be harder to find

Comment: @Rock updated my answer to consider the update from your question. Unfortunately the `SPLIT` function is not available in your Excel version. The solution provided by @horseyride works great for people don't have this function available I love Power Query it is very powerful to carry out basic ETL operations. I updated my answer for learning purpose for users who want to get familiar with the capabilities of this new set of Excel functions.

Comment: Thanks @David Leal I like google sheets too but forced to use Excel at work. Its shame that many functions are not available depending on version of excel we are using