# Repeat values n times where n could also be 0.5

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, let, excel-lambda

I saw the following question on here regarding repeating values:
[List number of lessons including half lessons based on Number of lessons and lesson name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74167929/12634230)

This question needed an older Excel version, I liked the problem statement and liked searching for a solution including new Excel formulas.

We have the following data:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | 1 | w |
| *2* | 5 | e |
| *3* | 4.5 | o |
| *4* | 2.5 | Win |
| *5* | 1.5 | pp |

The idea is to repeat the value of column B the number of times mentioned in column A.
The challenge is that column A could also contain non-integers (`0.5`-values only).
If a `0.5`-value is used it should repeat the value in column B the number of integers in A and show `0.5`  and the text value stacked with `0.5`  and the next text value.

In this case the expected result would be:

| expected |
| --- |
| w |
| e |
| e |
| e |
| e |
| e |
| o |
| o |
| o |
| o |
| 0.5 o, 0.5 Win |
| Win |
| Win |
| pp |
| 0.5 pp |

I managed to get a working solution in Office 365:

```
=LET(
    data,A1:B5,
        A,INDEX(data,,1),
        B,INDEX(data,,2),       
            s,SCAN(0,A,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
            si,INT(s),
            sr,ROUNDUP(s,0),
            sm,SEQUENCE(MAX(sr)),
                mr,XMATCH(sm,sr,1),
                mi,XMATCH(sm,si,1),
IFERROR(
    IF(mr=mi,
        INDEX(B,mr,),
        "0.5 "&INDEX(B,mr,)&", 0.5 "&INDEX(B,mi)),
    "0.5 "&INDEX(B,mr,)))
```

and Tony got an answer using FILTERXML coming real close in the original question:
`=FILTERXML(REPLACE(CONCAT(REPT("</c><c>" & B2:B6,FLOOR(A2:A6,1)) & IF(A2:A6-INT(A2:A6)>0,"</c><c>" & A2:A6-INT(A2:A6) & B2:B6,"")),2,2,"p")&"</c></p>","//c")`

Would this be realisable in Excel 2013?

Comment: OP is using Excel 2010, and `FILTERXML()` doesn't works with that version of Excel. OP had posted the same query in Facebook as well, even there she has not clarified her output.

Comment: I commented that there already. Still the question itself is nice and I'm curious for a Excel 2013 (FILTERXML) solution.

Comment: Oops sorry, i didn't checked that sorry, apologize for the same

Comment: No problem, it's a question about repeating text anyway 

Comment: Would you be interested in a somewhat less verbose ms365 version avoiding `TEXTJOIN()`?

Comment: @JvdV curious, yes. More ways to a solution also might help lead us to an answer for older Excel versions

Answer (score 3):

I have definitely lost touch with these long-dreaded formulas in previous versions of Excel. So unfortunate `CONCAT()` is not available for example. Either way, I think the following could work:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,INDEX(B$1:B$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A1)-1,MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),ROUND(A$1:A$5,0)))+1,1)))+0.5=INDEX(A$1:A$5,MATCH(INDEX(B$1:B$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A1)-1,MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),ROUND(A$1:A$5,0)))+1,1)),B$1:B$5,0)),"0.5 ","")&INDEX(B$1:B$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A1)-1,MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),ROUND(A$1:A$5,0)))+1,1))
```

Obviously the above is an array-entered formula and needs to be dragged down.

---

For ms365 users, try:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,REPT(B1:B5&"|",A1:A5)&REPT("0.5 "&B1:B5,MOD(A1:A5,1)>0),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,,"|",1)))),1)
```

Based on a little trick to stack output while running `REDUCE()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73853318/9758194)

Comment: Nice approach. Note that the expected result requires to show 0.5 of the current row and 0.5 of the next value in the same cell. So `C12` would show `0.5 o, 0.5 Win`

Comment: Ahh I missed that @P.b. Back to the drawing board I assume. That would make it rather complex I expect having to work around the missing `CONCAT()` =)

Comment: @P.b, `CONCATENATE()` does not take arrays or ranges in just a single parameter. You actually have to fill out each parameter to concatenate values. Hence it's not very usefull at all. Rather use the ampersand.

Comment: @P.b, note that there is **no** `CONCAT()` available in Exel 2013 despite the answer given in the linked question.

Comment: I wonder `REDUCE()` has array capability for output result for horizontally and vertically. It can through end results as array while other lambda helper functions can't. They can provide array output only vertically.

Comment: Yes, @Harun24hr, horizontally is also perfectly possible with `REDUCE()`.

Comment: @P.b I came to the conclusion it's not possible. I'll be happy to be proven wrong but I ended up in a very long repetitive formula that I could throw out of the window the minute I altered the input data to, say: 0.5 w, 0.5 e, 0.5 o, 0.5 Win and 0.5 pp or any sort of alternation. I'll stick to the answer given as I feel it is closest to the desired output I can get using Excel 2013. Again....happy to be proven wrong without using all sort of helper columns.

Comment: I managed to get a working solution. Got stack at matching to A running SUM, but couldn't match to that (with XMATCH it works though). Stepping to MMULT fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I been there thinking I got stuff working but what happens if you change the 1 W into 0.5 W? @P.b

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X17U8.png it works as expected. It shows `0.5 w, 0,5 e` followed by 4 lines `e` and `0.5 e, 0.5 o`; altogether 0.5 for w and 5 (0.5+1+1+1+1+0.5) for e, etc.

Comment: That was definitely not clear to me but if that's the expected results then kudos to you @P.b

Comment: Lol, so you might have gotten there already, but didn't think it was expected maybe

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a working version:

```
=IF(ROW()>CEILING(SUM($A$1:$A$5),1),       
    "",       
    IFERROR(IF(
               INDEX($B$1:$B$5,
                     MATCH(TRUE,
                           ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(CEILING(MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),A$1:A$5),1)),        
                           0))           
               =INDEX($B$1:$B$5,
                      MATCH(TRUE,
                            ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(INT(MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),A$1:A$5))),
                            0)),
               INDEX($B$1:$B$5,
                     MATCH(TRUE,
                           ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(CEILING(MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),A$1:A$5),1)),
                           0)),
               "0.5 "&INDEX($B$1:$B$5,
                            MATCH(TRUE,
                                  ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(CEILING(MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),A$1:A$5),1)),
                                  0))
               &", 0.5 "&INDEX($B$1:$B$5,
                               MATCH(TRUE,
                                     ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(INT(MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),A$1:A$5))),
                                     0))),
            "0.5 "&INDEX($B$1:$B$5,
                         MATCH(TRUE,
                               ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(CEILING(MMULT(IF(ROW(A$1:A$5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:A$5))=TRUE,1,0),A$1:A$5),1)),
                               0))))
```

Needless to say this is an array-formula and requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

[image]