# Separate numbers and text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-manipulation

Is there an Excel formula I can write in Excel to separate a combination of numbers and text from a cell?

col A is how the data is formatted, cols b - i are how I need them to be:

| col A | col b | col c | col d | col e | col f | col g | col h | col i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1EA/1PK/16BX/124CA | 1 | EA | 1 | PK | 16 | BX | 124 | CA |
| 1EA/6CA | 1 | EA | 6 | CS |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have two trailing letters '[A-Z]' in each concatenated value, have a go with:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,A1:A2,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(b,"/"),TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,REPLACE(c,LEN(c)-1,0,"|")),"|"))))),""),1)
```

To do this irrespective of the amount of trailing characters after digits:

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,A1:A2,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(b,ROW(1:10)-1,,1),d,SUBSTITUTE(TOROW(WRAPCOLS(HSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(b,c,,1),c),COUNTA(c))),"/",),IFERROR(--d,d))))),""),1)
```

Idea here is to delimit each input in recursion by any digit. The remainder could then be input as an array to delimit the input by to retrieve all numbers. Some other functions will then shuffle around both these arrays to `VSTACK()` properly to our previous rows of the output.

Comment: Nice how you can get the textsplit to spill down. See my reply. Would you know a way to apply that?

Comment: @p.b thanks. I'm not behind a pc now but will have a look this weekend!

Comment: @P.b, added an option to do this irrespective of length of trailing characters. Note that this is then also does not rely on `TEXTJOIN()` and it's possible limits of concatenating the entire input first. It's basically a recursive function to take a single input and `VSTACK()` it to the previous rows of the output.

Comment: Very nice. So REDUCE behaves kind of like SCAN/BYROW?

Comment: @P.b, yes that's a good way to describe this behaviour. A very nice alternative to the limits of TEXTSPLIT, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73853318/9758194). Usefull in more instances where one would want to look back at previous iterations too.

Comment: Found more use for it already https://stackoverflow.com/a/74326770/12634230

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that would spill the result, numbers are numbers and text (or number) length can be variable:

```
=LET(number,TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(SEQUENCE(1,26,65)),,1),
     text,TEXTSPLIT(A1,SEQUENCE(1,10,0),,1),
     spill,TOROW(VSTACK(number,text),,1),
     remove,SUBSTITUTE(spill,"/",""),
IFERROR(--remove,remove))
```

`number` splits the text by any capital letter.
`text` splits the text by any number.
`spill` is the result, but numbers are still text. This is fixed with `remove`

[image]

Mine doesn't spill by row and needs dragged. I think JvdV may know how to fix that.

Edit to spill down also:

```
=LET(data,A1:A2, 
     join,TEXTJOIN("|",,data), 
          number,TEXTSPLIT(join,CHAR(SEQUENCE(1,26,65)),,1), 
          text,TEXTSPLIT(join,SEQUENCE(1,10,0),,1), 
          spill,TOROW(VSTACK(number,text),,1), 
          spilldown,IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("•",1,spill),"•","|",1),""), 
          remove,SUBSTITUTE(spilldown,"/",""),
IFERROR(--remove,remove))
```

[image]