# Set row maximum for FILTER formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset where I will be using the FILTER formula to extract specific values relative to an individual. For each individual, I only want to be extracting the last 2 scores. The data is in descending chronological order so effectively I just need the first 2 entries that exist.

| Year | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | A | 50 |
| 2022 | B | 40 |
| 2022 | C | 60 |
| 2021 | A | 10 |
| 2021 | B | 5 |
| 2020 | A | 90 |
| 2020 | B | 76 |
| 2019 | A | 45 |
| 2019 | C | 12 |
| 2018 | A | 14 |
| 2017 | A | 13 |

Using a dataset similar to the one attached, if I wasn't interested in only the last 2 scores, I would use something like

`=FILTER(A:C,B:B=B1)` `B1` for `A`, `B2` for `B` etc.

But doing that would give me `6` rows for `A`, `3` for `B` and `2` for `C`. To standardize this, I only want to consider, at max, `2` results per individual. How do I change the FILTER formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use entire column references: `FILTER`'s *include* parameter processes all cells passed to it, so you're effectively asking it to compute more than a million calculations, even if you only have a few hundred rows' worth of data.

You could use `TAKE` if your version of Excel has that function:

`=TAKE(FILTER(A1:C12,B1:B12=B2),2)`

or else `INDEX` with `SEQUENCE`:

`=INDEX(FILTER(A1:C12,B1:B12=B2),SEQUENCE(2),SEQUENCE(,3))`

If you're not sure how to create a dynamic reference to the last-used row, define *LRow* within Name Manager as:

`=MATCH("Ω",$B:$B)`

after which the first of the above becomes:

`=TAKE(FILTER(A1:INDEX(C:C,LRow),B1:INDEX(B:B,LRow)=B2),2)`

Comment: Nice trick on `"Ω"`

Comment: Works on text only, but makes it even more neat to know.

Answer (score 4):

Using a trick I learned from JvdV here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73853318/12634230 using REDUCE to stack calculation results, even if they're spills:

```
=LET(data,A2:C12,
     names,INDEX(data,,2),
DROP( 
     REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(names),LAMBDA(a,b,   
            VSTACK(a,TAKE(FILTER(data,names=b),2)))),
     1))
```

[image]

Comment: clever solution, initially I was thinking of something like this to create a dynamic `VSTACK` but I was not able to do it. The only "limitation" (but it was stated as an assumption) is that the input data set needs to already be sorted by year, but it can be extended to unsorted data, taking into account the year for sorting on the fly. Good trick to take into account for any other similar situations

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that **preserves the original order** of the input data since it uses `FILTER` and it **doesn't require to have the input data already be sorted**. It uses the idea of ranking the year within a group of items under the same name:

```
=LET(set, A2:C12, years, INDEX(set,,1), names, INDEX(set,,2),
 rank, MAP(names, years, LAMBDA(n,y, SUMPRODUCT((names=n) * (years > y))+1)),
 FILTER(set, rank <= 2)
)
```

[image: sample excel file]

This calculation does the magic:

```
SUMPRODUCT((names=n) * (years > y))+1
```

it ranks `years` **by group of names**. Here is the intermediate output of `rank`:

| Year | Name | Score | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | A | 50 | 1 |
| 2022 | B | 40 | 1 |
| 2022 | C | 60 | 1 |
| 2021 | A | 10 | 2 |
| 2021 | B | 5 | 2 |
| 2020 | A | 90 | 3 |
| 2020 | B | 76 | 3 |
| 2019 | A | 45 | 4 |
| 2019 | C | 12 | 2 |
| 2018 | A | 14 | 5 |
| 2017 | A | 13 | 6 |

it ranks in descending order each year for the same name. The highest year will be `1`, the second-highest will be `2`, and so on. Because we want up the second highest rank for each group, we need to filter by `rank` lower or equal to `2`.

Comment: Nice approach too.