# Excel: Split rows of table in multiple rows based on different cell values

Tags: excel, split, excel-tables

I have a CSV that contains multiple entries per cell per row:

| Name | Friends | Family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Simon, Kevin, Patrick | Mum, Dad |
| Jane | Clara, George | Grandpa, Grandma |

I want to transform it to this, so that each row contains only one pair. Is that possible without VBA? I think I could do this in VBA, but I would prefer a simpler way, so that my team is not dependent on VBA code. I played around with "Text to columns", but did not yet find a way to solve this.

| Name | Friends and/or family |
| --- | --- |
| John | Simon |
| John | Kevin |
| John | Patrick |
| John | Mum |
| John | Dad |
| Jane | Clara |
| Jane | George |
| Jane | Grandpa |
| Jane | Grandma |

Comment: Did you look into Powerquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this: Excel or Power Query.

### Excel

This is one way of doing it under Excel. You can try the following in cell `E2` (*Formula 1*):

```
=LET(input, A2:C3, fAndF, SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(input,,2) & "," & INDEX(input,,3), 
   ", ",","), names, INDEX(input,,1),
 GETCOL, LAMBDA(x, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",, x),,",",TRUE)),
 mapresult, MAP(names, fAndF, LAMBDA(name,f,
  LET(num, LEN(f) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(f, ",","")) + 1, REPT(name&",",num)))),
 HSTACK(GETCOL(mapresult), GETCOL(fAndF))
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: For large dataset the previous solution has a limitation, due to [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function. The maximum number of text you can concatenate is `253`. In order to circumvent that you can use the following approach based on `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK` functions to incrementally add new elements as we iterate (`Formula 2`):

```
=LET(input, A2:C3, fAndF, SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(input,,2) & "," & 
 INDEX(input,,3), ", ",","),names, INDEX(input,,1),
 DROP(REDUCE("", names, LAMBDA(ac, name, VSTACK(ac, LET(
  ff, TEXTSPLIT(XLOOKUP(name, names, fAndF), ","), 
  DROP(REDUCE("", ff, LAMBDA(acc, f, VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(name,f)))),1)
 )))),1)
)
```

### Power Query

With Power Query, there is no need to use M-code all the functionalities required are provided by the UI. Here is the corresponding M-code (*Advanced Editor*):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TB_INPUT"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Friends", type text}, 
      {"Family", type text}}),
    RemoveExtraSpaceAfterComma = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",", ",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,
      {"Friends", "Family"}),
    #"Merge Friend and Family" = Table.CombineColumns(RemoveExtraSpaceAfterComma,{"Friends", "Family"},
      Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"F&F"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merge Friend and Family", 
      {{"F&F", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta 
      [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "F&F")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

it will produce the following output:
[image: sample output in Power Query]

### Explanation

#### Excel

For *Formula 1*, we use use `LET` for easy reading and composition. The name `fAndF` represents the concatenation by a row of **Friend** and **Family** columns. We remove also the space of the comma (`,`) delimiter.

`GETCOL` is `LAMBDA` user-defined function. To convert an array of comma-delimited values on each row into a single column.

We use a `MAP` function to determine how many times we need to repeat the **Name** column value. The `num`:

```
LEN(f) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(f, ",","")) + 1
```

is a trick to determine how many rows we need by counting the total number of commas (`,`).

The name `mapresult` generates the following output:

```
John,John,John,John,John,
Jane,Jane,Jane,Jane,
```

Now, all we need to do is to join both rows via `TEXTJOIN`, then split again by comma via `TEXTSPLIT` and this is what the user function `GETCOL` does.

**Note**: The fourth input argument in `TEXTSPLIT` (in `GETCOL`), is set to `TRUE` to avoid generating an empty row with the last delimiter at the end.

Finally, we combine the result via `HSTACK`.

For *Formula 2*, we take a different approach. We use a pattern for avoiding *nested array error* that `TEXTSPLIT` produces and other functions. Check the answer of this question: [How to split texts from dynamic range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852522/how-to-split-texts-from-dynamic-range) provided by: @JvdV. The main idea consists of combining `DROP`, `REDUCE` and `VSTACK` functions to produce a recursion to add rows on each new iteration. We use this idea twice. One for each `names` and the other one for `fAndF` items for a given `name` on first `REDUCE` call.

For each `name` on first `REDUCE` call we find via `XLOOKUP` the corresponding `fAndF` values, then we invoke `TEXTSPLIT` to get the corresponding array (`ff`) and for each element of `ff` (`f`) we invoke the second `REDUCE` call adding a `1x2` row with the `name` and the corresponding `f` value via `HSTACK`.

Under this pattern, we need to remove the first row, that contains the initialization value of the accumulator (`ac`, `acc`). The pattern is always the same:

```
DROP(REDUCE("", array, LAMBDA(acc, arr, VSTACK(acc, func))),1)
```

and `func`, is where we do the calculation to build the content of the row we want to add. Usually we need to create additional variables and we encapsulate the calculation inside a `LET` function call.

#### Power Query

Once we have the data defined in an Excel Table, then in Power Query view.

Remove extra space in the comma delimiter. We select both columns **Friend** and **Family** columns and then: *Home->Replace Values* searching for `,`  and replacing it with `,`.

Select again **Friend** and **Family** columns then *Transform->Merge Column*. We name the merged column: **F&F** and we indicate the *Separator*. Here is the output:

[image: PQ: merge two columns]

Now we need to split the column: *Home -> Split Column -> By Delimiter*. In the *Advanced options* select: *Rows*, indicating we want to do the spit by rows. Here are the configuration options:

[image: PQ: Split columns by delimiter]

As @Ron Rosenfeld pointed out in the comments section. Another way of doing it is as follows:

After removing extra space after the comma (`#RemovedExtraSpaceAfterComma`) Select **Family** and **Friend** columns, then right-click and select: *Unpivot Column*s. Select the resulting **Value** column and *Home->Split Column->By Delimiter* and in *Advanced options* select *Rows*. Finally, remove the **Attribute** column.

Here is the M-code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TB_INPUT"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Friends", type text}, {"Family", type text}}),
    RemoveExtraSpaceAfterComma = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",", ",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Friends", "Family"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(RemoveExtraSpaceAfterComma, {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns", 
      {{"Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta 
        [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: In PQ, conceptually might be simpler, instead of merging, to just `Unpivot`. Then do your `split by comma delimiter` into rows and clean up the spaces using `Trim`.

Comment: Thanks, @RonRosenfeld I was able to reproduce your suggestion, about the same number of steps, but good to know there is another way to do it.

Comment: Thank you David for this detailed answer! Tried both solutions, both work. Will stick with the Power Query solution as the other one breaks down when the content of one cell is too large, apparently TEXTJOIN has a character limit. 
I learned something new from both solutions, really appreciate that you took the time to write a detailed explanation for both. Al the best!

Comment: Thanks @JohannesEngelhardt, yes `TEXTJOIN` has a limit you can concatenate up to 253 texts. Check the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c). I think there is a way to circumvent it, if I find it I will update the answer.

Comment: @JohannesEngelhardt I found a way to avoid using `TEXTJOIN`. I updated my answer and documented the solution, please check it when you get a chance to confirm with your real data that it works and let me know. Thanks