# excel - how to Transpose column value to row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to Transpose data from table A to table B, please help.

[image]

I try to use excel Transpose data, however I don't know what should I do

Comment: are you happy to use VBA?

Comment: You are not transposing, you are unpivoting.

Comment: Please check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435042/excel-split-rows-of-table-in-multiple-rows-based-on-different-cell-values/74436257#74436257), it is a similar problem applied to a different dataset.

Comment: Power Query an option ?

Comment: Voted to close as dup. Both answers will show you how to unpivot data. Let us know if you are helped. If not, we can vote to re-open.