# Combining TEXTSPLIT with BYROW to return a spilled array

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I can use `TEXTSPLIT()` on an individual cell with no problem, but I want to use a single formula to split a list of names.

This works:

[image]

However, this doesn't:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? `BYROW()` works fine with most functions, but it doesn't like `TEXTSPLIT()` for some reason.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 4):

The error is due to the fact that, when using `BYROW`, the `LAMBDA` must return only a single value, not two values.

There may be more efficient methods, but one way of getting your desired output to spill over the range with just a single formula:

```
 =HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(F2:F4," "),TEXTAFTER(F2:F4," "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`REDUCE()` could be good choice in this case. Reduce function can output result dynamically expanded both horizontally and vertically.

```
=IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,A2:INDEX(A2:A50000,COUNTA(A2:A50000)),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b," ")))),1),"")
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73853318/5514747) by @JvdV to one of my question. This is more efficient to handle multi delimiter.

[image]