# Separate data in Excel with 3 types of delimiters - Space, hyphen and =>

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, m

I recently received an Excel file and I'm struggling to separate the commission column to make my work easier in the future.
I have 3 different types of delimiters for the percentage - space, hyphen and =>.

This is my sample data:

| supplier | date | commission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adeccoss | 1/1/2023 | intre 4-6 mil $ - 2% 6-10 mil $ - 3% >10 mil $ - 5% |
| gigel | 5/7/2023 | intre 3-5 mil $ => 3% 5-8 mil $ => 5% >8 mil $ => 7% |
| floris | 4/4/2023 | intre 0.5-2 mil $ 1% 2-3 mil $ 2% 3-5 mil $ 3.5% 5-6 mil $ 4.5% >6 mil $ 6% |

I tried with textafter function ,texsplit functions using Power Query but I can't get the data in the desired output as you may see:

| supplier | date | commision | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| adeccoss | 1/1/2023 | 4-6 mil $ | 2% |
| adeccoss | 1/1/2023 | 6-10 mil $ | 3% |
| adeccoss | 1/1/2023 | >10 mil $ | 5% |
| gigel | 5/7/2023 | 3-5 mil $ | 3% |
| gigel | 5/7/2023 | 5-8 mil $ | 5% |
| gigel | 5/7/2023 | >8 mil $ | 7% |
| floris | 4/4/2023 | 0-2 mil $ | 1% |
| floris | 4/4/2023 | 2-3 mil $ | 2% |
| floris | 4/4/2023 | 3-5 mil $ | 3.5% |
| floris | 4/4/2023 | 5-6 mil $ | 4.5% |
| floris | 4/4/2023 | >6 mil $ | 6% |

Can you please help with any solution using formulas in office 365 or Power Query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not elegegant, but it works:

```
=LET(res,
 WRAPROWS(
     TOCOL(
       TEXTSPLIT(
           TEXTAFTER(
               SUBSTITUTE(
                  SUBSTITUTE(
                     SUBSTITUTE(
                        SUBSTITUTE(
                           SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2:C4),"% ","%|"&A2:A4&"|"&B2:B4&"|"),
                           "$ -","$"),
                        "$ =>","$"),
                     "$","$|"),
                  "intre","|"&A2:A4&"|"&B2:B4&"|"),
              "|",SEQUENCE(,99)),
          "|"),
        2),
    4),
IFERROR(--res,res))
```

[image]

or using lambda for the repeating SUBSTITUTE:

```
=LET(a,{"% ";"$ -";"$ =>";"$";"intre"},
     b,{"%|#|";"$";"$";"$|";"|#|"},
res,
WRAPROWS(
    TOCOL(
      TEXTSPLIT(
          TEXTAFTER(
              SUBSTITUTE(
                 REDUCE(C2:C4,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
                 LAMBDA(x,y,
                        SUBSTITUTE(x,INDEX(a,y),
                                     INDEX(b,y)))),
                 "#",
                 A2:A4&"|"&B2:B4),
              "|",SEQUENCE(,99)),
          "|"),
        2),
      4),
IFERROR(--res,res))
```

Comment: Nice, just a comment, the recursive substitution, can be simplified as follows: `REDUCE(C2:C4,a,LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,XLOOKUP(y,a,b)))`

Comment: @DavidLeal you're correct, that would be shorter.

Answer (score 4):

There's plenty of answers here already, but just for kicks, here's one more that uses lambda recursion within `LET()`:

```
=LET(
F, LAMBDA(X,arr,[val],[num],
   LET(
   n, IF(ISOMITTED(num), 1, num),
   a, INDEX(arr, n, {1,2}),
   b, WRAPROWS(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(INDEX(arr, n, 3),"intre"),,{"$ -","$ =>","$","%"},TRUE)),2),
   c, IFNA(HSTACK(a, IFERROR(b/100, b&" $")), a),
   v, IF(ISOMITTED(val), c, VSTACK(val, c)),
   IF(n<ROWS(arr), X(X, arr, v, n+1), v))),
F(F, A2:C4, HSTACK(A1:C1, "percent")))
```

**Results:**

[image: lambda_recursion.png]

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @DavidLeal in the comments below, this technique should only be used on small datasets, due to the limitations of recursive lambdas in Excel. Fortunately, though, the logic used in the formula above is very similar to that of `REDUCE()` and can easily be re-written as follows:

```
=LET(
arr, A2:C4,
REDUCE(HSTACK(A1:C1, "percent"), SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)), LAMBDA(v,n,
   LET(
   a, INDEX(arr, n, {1,2}),
   b, WRAPROWS(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(arr, n, 3),,{"intre","$ -","$ =>","$","%"},TRUE)),2),
   VSTACK(v, IFNA(HSTACK(a, IFERROR(b/100, b&" $")), a))))))
```

I've also simplified the text manipulation process here by removing `TEXTAFTER()` and adding "intre" to the *[row_delimiter]* array.

Comment: Nice solution, using recursion, just take into account the limitation this approach has for a large data set, due to the current operant stack limit in Excel: `1,024`. Check the section: *Word to wise* from this article: [LAMBDA Formulaic Recursion: It’s All About ME!](https://www.sumproduct.com/thought/lambda-formulaic-recursion-its-all-about-me)

Comment: @DavidLeal Good to know… thanks for the tip! They are fun to play with, though. :-)

Comment: This also a good approach, but keep in mind `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern also has performance issue for a large dataset. We have discussed it extensively in SO. We try to avoid it unless there is no other alternative. For example check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893966/vstack-and-textsplit-on-dynamic-ranges

Comment: @DavidLeal For sure, I’ve read that about REDUCE/VSTACK before too. Better than the recursion limits on LAMBDA, though. One thing I didn’t know was that REDUCE/VSTACK performs better than MAKEARRAY… that’s a bit of a surprise.

Comment: Yes for this example yes, but in general `MAKEARRAY` performs better than `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern, there are several example  also in SO that shows it.  Usually non-LAMBDA approaches perform better.

Comment: @DavidLeal Agreed! It’s funny though, since I’ve been on here, one of the most commonly used methods I’ve seen is REDUCE/VSTACK. It seems like half the challenge is to come up with the shortest or most clever single-cell solution, when there’s plenty of old-school ways to get the job done in maybe 2 or 3 quick steps. Personally, I lean more towards VBA solutions when dealing with repetitive tasks. But there’s no denying dynamic arrays are fun! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are cleaner ways but here is one solution.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XY/dDoIwDEZfpVncHWU/XcEbn2RyYXCSJSgJ6Ps7AkPhrv3WntN5L2730LbDNIlCGGWU1ZZSGV/vMYDDCp6xhxMgWAkVGr31JOH60ZrCX8ZSNIUXXexCnyCs6j2PkNfZy7I7UxjPh5Az+vhQL/xHP4xxPtgptxfoktGuS0aCRVqbdP1PTiXP2vw3V27CHFVJ1HwB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [supplier = _t, date = _t, commision = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"supplier", type text}, {"date", type date}, {"commision", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type"," - ","|",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"commision"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value"," => ","|",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"commision"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","$ ","$|",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"commision"}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","%","%~",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"commision"}),
    #"Replaced Value4" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value3","intre","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"commision"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value4", {{"commision", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("~", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "commision"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Delimiter", each [commision] <> ""),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "commision", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"commision", "percent"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"commision", type text}, {"percent", Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query you can also split by multiple delimiters in a single step. Then you can combine things to return the commission and percent

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"supplier", type text}, {"date", type date}, {"commission", type text}}),

//Split by multiple delimiters
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({" "," - ","=>"})([commission])),

//Create lists of the commissions and percentages
    #"Split Commission" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Comission", (r)=>
        let 
            pos = List.PositionOf(r[Custom],"$",Occurrence.All),
            coms = List.Accumulate(
                pos,
                {},
                (s,c)=>s & {Text.Combine(List.Range(r[Custom],c-2,3)," ")}),
            pct =List.Select(r[Custom], each Text.EndsWith(_,"%"))
        in 
            List.Zip({coms,pct})),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Commission",{"commission", "Custom"}),

//Expand to new rows and then to the columns
    #"Expanded Comission" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Comission"),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Comission", 
        {"Comission", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "#(tab)"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Comission", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(tab)", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Comission", "Percent"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Comission", type text}, {"Percent", Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach to @P.b, it doesn't have a fix size of `99`, instead it identifies the maximum possible length and it treats the first two columns separately:

```
=LET(A,A2:A4, B,B2:B4, C,C2:C4,
 old,{"$","%"," => "," - ","intre "}, new, {"$,","%;","","",","},sep, {",",";"},
 clean, REDUCE(C, old, LAMBDA(ac,a,SUBSTITUTE(ac,a,XLOOKUP(a,old,new)))),
 nRec, LEN(clean) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(clean, ";","")),
 split, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(clean,sep, SEQUENCE(,2*MAX(nRec))),sep),
 seq, 1*MID(CONCAT(REPT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(nRec)), nRec)), SEQUENCE(SUM(nRec)),1),
 VSTACK({"supplier","date","commision","percentage"},
  HSTACK(INDEX(A,seq), INDEX(B,seq), TRIM(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(split,2),2)))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

`clean` prepares the column **C** to delimit each record (`;`), and within the record to delimit each value (`,`), i.e. commission, and percentage. `nRec` counts the number of records per row of column **C**. The variable `sep`, considers both delimiters: records and values (you can use other delimiters of your convenience if you expect such values will be present in the column). The instance number of each delimiter is determined by `SEQUENCE(,2*MAX(nRec)))` considering the row with the maximum number of records.

We use the trick that `TEXTSPLIT` doesn't work well for 2D arrays, it splits just by the first element only which for this case is convenient to remove the remaining part of `TEXTAFTER` output.

To generate the repetition for the first two columns (`seq`) based on the number of records we use the following:

```
1*MID(CONCAT(REPT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(nRec)), nRec)), SEQUENCE(SUM(nRec)),1)
```

You can also use the following instead:

```
idx, SEQUENCE(ROWS(nRec)),
seq, INDEX(idx,XMATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(nRec)),MMULT(N(idx>=TOROW(idx)),nRec),1,2))
```

Longer, but probably more efficient for a large dataset. In both cases it generates the sequence: `1;1;1;2;2;2;;3;3;3;3;3` that will be used in `INDEX` for columns **A** and **B**. To generate the repeated values based on the number of records found on each row of column **C**.

Now we are ready to prepare the output: `TRIM(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(split,2),2))` arranges the column **C** values to the expected output. We remove the `N/A` with less number or records via the second input argument of `TOCOL`.

Finally, we use `VSTACK` and `HSTACK` to accommodate the final output.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is more elegant way of doing this, perhaps here is another approach you could try. However, like I say every time, will try to improvise more on it,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A2:C4,
     REDUCE(HSTACK("Supplier","Date","Commission","Percent"),SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),
     LAMBDA(φ,ε,VSTACK(φ,IFERROR(HSTACK(INDEX(α,ε,{1,2}),
     LET(_α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(INDEX(α,ε,3),"intre "),{" - ","=>"," "},,1),2),4),
         _φ, BYROW(TAKE(_α,,3),LAMBDA(p,TEXTJOIN(" ",,p))),
         _ε, DROP(_α,,3)/1,
         HSTACK(_φ,_ε))),
         INDEX(α,ε,{1,2}))))))
```

---