# VSTACK for dynamic sequences PRIOR to their creation*

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I am trying to find the VSTACK for any number of sequences that can be formulated as:

```
sequence(to_ - from_ + 1) + (from_ - 1)
```

where column headings to_ and from_ represent the start and end points of respective sequences. For instance, consider the following table of start and end points (from_, to_ resp.):

Example input/output and illustrating possible (albeit sub-optimal in relation to desired/robust soln for Q in hand)

**Input**

[image: inputs]

Given this, the desired output should vertically stack 32,46,95, and 45 (comprising sequences with one element each) on top of the (vertical) sequence ranging 48,49,..,57, and likewise for 65,66,..,90.

**Output**

This would give an output as follows:

[image: Desired output]

The manual way would look something like this:

```
=VSTACK(SEQUENCE(f2-e2+1)+e2-1, SEQUENCE(f3-e3+1)+e3-1 , … , SEQUENCE(f7-e7+1)+e7-1))
```

---

**Notes:**

*Note: this is specific to Office 365 compatible versions of Excel; no interest in helper functions, or soln involving VB, Python in Excel/Advanced Formula Editor add-ins etc.*

For reference, I have reviewed questions marked as 'similar' - these did not seem to be readily adaptable to the question in hand:

I have a plausible solution but it lacks parsimony, hoping someone is aware of a more tractable method (still fixing /tweaking so can share for possible refinement as req.).

---

**Related (but adequately different) Qs reviewed**

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893966/vstack-and-textsplit-on-dynamic-ranges) Q (top soln goes to hometown, courtesy @JvdV as of present posting)

- Cells already comprise concatenated lists with with suitable delimiter
- Direct application infeasible given when a series of sequences should necessitate the ByRow/LAMDBA duet or similar - further complicating matters
- Other solns utilized VB or were 'static' (i.e. similar to 'long method' above)

2. [Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-combine-dynamic-arrays-vertically.1177564/) is another variation - courtesy @MrExcel MVP

- clearly the format/set up is completely different with disjoint lists that appear to lend themselves to the 'long/manual' method - i.e. adding another 'dynamic list' requires manually updating the function to reference the appropriate 'added range/dynamic list)

3. SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1777638/in-excel-how-do-i-stack-a-very-large-set-of-columns) appears to have what I'm looking for with toCol for range of arrays, yet does not seem to work / after some adaptation, Q in hand
4. Chat-GPT didn't solve either, for interest's sake it did propose reduce function which hadn't occurred to me.

Conclusion: popularized techniques appear well-suited to cases where arrays do not first need to be created, i.e. 1 & 3 have these as a given already, in my case, these need to be created.

---

**Use Case**

Various advantages RE: data cleaning/analysis and preparation; e.g. in my case I want to reference all Unicode values that produce undesirable characters using Unichar; for the purpose of assimilating the necessary data for analysis.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of using `TOCOL()` function while doing a `BOOLEAN LOGIC` comparison:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, E2:F7,
     _To, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _NOfRows, SEQUENCE(,MAX(_To)),
     TOCOL(IFS((_NOfRows>=TAKE(_Data,,1))*(_NOfRows<=_To),_NOfRows),3))
```

---

- `_Data` --> Variable to store the dataset,
- `_To` --> Variable is the end of each start data,
- `NOfRows` --> Variable to get the max value from the range,
- Lastly, doing a `Boolean Logic` between the `_NOfRows` with the `_From` & `_To` if the criteria returns `TRUE`, it will give `_NOfRows` and if not returns `#N/A` which is parsed using `TOCOL()`;s function 2nd parameter as well using to stack vertically.

---

Bit shorter version of the above:

```
=LET(
     α, F2:F7,
     δ, SEQUENCE(,MAX(α)),
     TOCOL(δ/((δ>=E2:E7)*(δ<=α)),2))
```

---

**ADDENDUM:** One doesn't needs a `LAMBDA()` ***recursive*** helper function for the above question, as well, if someone makes such **basic typos** even when entering manually then could use the following, however one shouldn't do such **irregular/random typos**, to increase **#** of functions(too many functions to play makes excel to run ***slow, slower, slowest.....***).

```
=LET(
     _Data, IF(E2:E7>F2:F7,F2:F7&"|"&E2:E7,E2:E7&"|"&F2:F7),
     _Start, --TEXTBEFORE(_Data,"|"),
     _End, --TEXTAFTER(_Data,"|"),
     _NOfRows, SEQUENCE(,MAX(_End)),
     TOCOL(_NOfRows/((_NOfRows>=_Start)*(_NOfRows<=_End)),2))
```

---

Using `LAMBDA()` helper function called `MAKEARRAY()`

```
=LET(
     _Data, IF(E2:E7>F2:F7,F2:F7&"|"&E2:E7,E2:E7&"|"&F2:F7),
     _Start, --TEXTBEFORE(_Data,"|"),
     _End, --TEXTAFTER(_Data,"|"),
     _NOfRows, _End-_Start+1,
     TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_NOfRows),SUM(_NOfRows),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c<=INDEX(_NOfRows,r),INDEX(_Start,r)+c-1,p))),2))
```

---

[image]

---

Using `MAP()`

```
=LET(
     _Data, IF(E2:E7>F2:F7,F2:F7&"|"&E2:E7,E2:E7&"|"&F2:F7),
     _Start, --TEXTBEFORE(_Data,"|"),
     _End, --TEXTAFTER(_Data,"|"),
     _Max, MAX(_End-_Start+1),
     --TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&MAP(_Start,_End,LAMBDA(x,y,TEXTJOIN("|",,SEQUENCE(y-x+1,,x)))),"|",SEQUENCE(,_Max)),"|"),2))
```

---

Comment: Hi - great solns -- se my replies to your comments earlier though
- RE: 'by/Lambda duet' - note, I was the one who in fact dropped the 'reduce ' function into the thinking, further I was exceptionally careful in my choice of vernacular - recall the backdoor I left open with the convenient 'or related' description of what is required "ByRow/LAMDBA duet or similar "....

Comment: @JB-007 why do you want to use `LAMBDA()` helper function when it is possible without it. Also can you refer the link related with your comments to me, because I am not able to recall.

Comment: who said that I use it please? I merely said that using a sequence would invoke the lambda or similar. That said - I think that your approach might just be correct.  That's amaaing!

Comment: @JB-007 updated another method using `MAKEARRAY()` =) but clearly it is not required.

Comment: .@MayukhBhattacharya genius mate, pure genius.  Sometimes (perhaps often?) less is more.  I commend you for such a succinct / parsimonious soln that until recently completely evaded me.  Ta.

Comment: @JB-007 glad to know, thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

### Stack Sequences Defined By Two Columns

```
=LET(data,E2:F6,
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        start,INDEX(data,r,1),
        end,INDEX(data,r,2),
        s,end-start,
        step,SIGN(s),
        VSTACK(rr,SEQUENCE(s*step+1,,start,step))))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I received some excellent answers that I would not have thought about/known to improve the solution I mentioned that I had from the outset - given mine felt it too 'unwieldy'; i.e. far from elegant/prosaic - here it is, fyi (not sure how it managed to 'work' but had to go around a bit to get to the something that 'worked'):

```
=LET(x_,BYROW(AI2#,LAMBDA(a_,LET(a0_,INDEX(a_,0,1),a1_,INDEX(a_,0,2),b_,TEXTJOIN("¬",1,SEQUENCE(a1_-a0_+1)+(a0_-1)),c_,TEXTJOIN("¬",TRANSPOSE(b_),1),b_))),y_,TEXTJOIN("¬",1,x_),z_,TEXTSPLIT(y_,,"¬",1),z_)
```

[image: Unwieldy soln / attempt]

I'll add commentary below as req. to elaborate/close-off and keep admin folk off my back ☺

Comment: Feeling somewhat ashamed, I'm glad I raised this (despite) having a soln because it's provided several new functions /techniques to practice with and add to my arsenal. Likewise, I didn't feel that this problem (as set out here) had received as much attention previously as I might have hoped/expected - given my few examples.  No doubt someone will manage to find an identical question somewhere - but I looked reasonably well for 15-20 mins, then drew a line in the sand.  Many thanks to all who contributed.  This really helped - ta

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is for 365 but want to show the restraints of array functions.
This formula seems a very simple and clear approach, but works only on GOOGLESHEET.

With BYROW and also with TOCOL function but another SEQUENCE technic.

This formula with excel-online returns #CALC! error because of nested arrays are not supported.

```
=TOCOL(BYROW(E2:F7,LAMBDA(inp,sequence(1,index(inp,1,2)-index(inp,1,1)+1,index(inp,1,1)))),3)
```

The result is the same as in the posts.

Comment: This is great - but I guess I'm looking for a way around the nested error (in Excel ) - will raise a county for this in day or so,,,